# How to stop uTorrent on specific network?

Tags: network, automator, torrent

I go to a university where there is a weekly network usage limit, and I don't want uTorrent sucking it up.

I know the simplest way to go about stopping it is from working is closing it when I get to school or stopping my torrents, but this can result in me forgetting about it.

Is there an automated way to block uTorrent while I'm connected to this specific network?

Answer (score 2):

[MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) can be used for launching scripts based on using specific NetworkLinks or IP addresses.

Your applescript then should contain something like:

```
tell application "uTorrent" to quit
```